# deployment key not working on a git pull

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, bitbucket

I hve a private repo on bitbucket and I have deployment keys setup. They key is in the /root directory of my server and my projects are in the home directory. (IDK if that make s difference)

I have tried cloning the repository onto the server and it seems to work...meaning that it doesn't not ask me for any kind of authentication.

but the if I run a `git pull` from the repository on the server it asks me for authentication. I must be missing something simple here but I can't see what it is.

Comment: Did you clone the repository via `ssh` or `https` ?

Comment: cloned through ssh `git@bitbucket.org...`

Comment: Have you configured `git config --global user.name` and ``git config --global user.email` ?

Comment: explnantion posted in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had cloned my "working" repo a long time ago using https so the remote was setup with https.

When I added a deployment key to bitbucket, it automatically changed the repo clone link to SSH. When I copied the link to try cloning to see if SSH worked (after failing to work on my git `git pull`), I copied the SSH link.

I didn't realize my remote was setup with `https` and bitbucket changed the default to `ssh`

my solution was to do this...

```
git remote rm origin 
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org...
```

and then everything worked great.